# CodeIgniter Pass AJAX data back to conroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to open a form up to update a users details via AJAX. However I can't seem to pass anything back. Can I get some help with it?

My thinking is that there is a HTML form that is hidden for now, when the user clicks on a button, the row id and is sent via ajax to the controller which is then sent to the model. How do I retrieve the data back to the controller and display it on the form?

So far nothing appears in the console logs or alerts.

My View

```
<div id="edit-dialog">
<?php echo form_open('manager/users/edit_user'); ?>
<p>First Name : <input type="text" name="firstname"/></p>
<p>Last Name : <input type="text" name="lastname"/></p>
<p>NRIC : <input type="text" name="nric"/></p>
<p>Address : <input type="text" name="address"/></p>
<p>Username : <input type="text" name="username"/></p>
</form>
</div>
```

My Jquery code

```
$('.editlink').on('click', function() {
var user_id = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
    url: '/manager/agent/users/get_user',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{'id':user_id},
    cache:false,
    success:function(result){
            $("#edit-dialog").show();
         //     console.log(result);
          var result = $.parseJSON(result); 
            console.log(result.id);
          //    $('#name').html(result.id); 
          //    $('#id').html(result.id);

}});

});
```

My Controller

```
function get_user()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->load->model('user');
    $data = $this->user->retrieve($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
    return json_encode($data);
}

public function retrieve($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        return $query->result_array();  
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result_array();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to echo or die in controller

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

or

```
die(json_encode($data));
```

You will get data in result variable

```
success:function(result){
var result = $.parseJSON( result );
 $('#name').html(result.name);
 $('#id').html(result.id);
}
```

`

Comment: I get an object returned to me. How do I access the details of that object? Like how do I get the name, id of the user?

Comment: var result = $.parseJSON( result );
$('#name').html(result.name);
$('#id').html(result.id);

Comment: I think this will help you!!

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! But I seem to be getting a syntax error with the var result = $.parseJSON line. My console log shows unexpected token o

Comment: Can you pls attach screen shot.

Comment: I have edited the code. i'm not sure how to attach a screenshot

Comment: `data:{'id':user_id}` should be `data:{ id: user_id }`.

Comment: I've changed it. But still the same results. I'm not sure where this error is at

Comment: I realised that parseJSON is the problem. Looking into other methods of parsing as I can see the results in the console log currently

Comment: I realized that I do not need to parse the results as result[0].id already gives me a proper answer. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

a couple suggestions

make your ajax calls domain relative

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: '/manager/agent/users/get_user',
...
```

primarily, i don't see that you have the `editlink` class on any elements, therefore the listener doesn't seem to be attached to anything. make sure `class="editlink"` is on any element that should take the `click`

Comment: Oh the editlink is a button in a table that i did not show. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks! I've changed the url. So far I've done what sriAnkush has suggested but im getting a syntax error with one of the lines.